# how to make table fluid

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a table in my .aspx page I want to make it fluid. My other layout is fluid but table is stick to its position. The CSS is

```
#reportingEmployee
{
font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
width:100%;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
#reportingEmployee td, #reportingEmployee th 
{
font-size:1em;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;/* #98bf21;*/
padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;
}
#reportingEmployee th 
{
font-size:1.1em;
text-align:left;
padding-top:5px;
padding-bottom:4px;
    background-color: #ef0909;/*#A7C942;*/
color:#ffffff;
}
#reportingEmployee tr.alt td 
{
color:#000000;
background-color:#EAF2D3;
}
```

and the HTML is

Name of employee
                                
                                
                                    Date
                                
                                
                                    Time-in
                                
                                
                                    Time-out
                                
                                
                                    Late Arrival
                                
                                
                                    Early Departure
                                
                                
                                    Absent
                                
                            
                            
                                
                                    Bilal
                                
                                
                                    25-11-2013
                                
                                
                                    10:00
                                
                                
                                    20:00

```
                         <tr class="alt">
                            <td>
                                Bilal
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                25-11-2013
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                10:00
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                20:00
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <center>
                                    <img src="../img/tick.png" />
                                </center>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <center>


            <img src="../img/cross.png" />
                            </center>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <center>
                                <img src="../img/cross.png" />
                            </center>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

Comment: please look here http://www.creativebloq.com/css3/create-fluid-layouts-html5-and-css3-9122768

Answer (score -1):

Try adding a with based on % to your columns:

```
#reportingEmployee td, #reportingEmployee th 
{
font-size:1em;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;/* #98bf21;*/
    padding:3px 7px 2px 7px;
    width:14%;
}
```